# opencv and mediapipe download error keep happens

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pip, mediapipe

i am using mac and i got python 3.9.15 in anaconda. I tried to download cv2 by "pip install opencv-python" but respond was:

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.5 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.6 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.21.2 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0rc1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0rc1, 1.19.0rc2, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5, 1.20.0rc1, 1.20.0rc2, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.20.3, 1.21.0rc1, 1.21.0rc2, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.22.0rc1, 1.22.0rc2, 1.22.0rc3, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.22.2, 1.22.3, 1.22.4, 1.23.0rc1, 1.23.0rc2, 1.23.0rc3, 1.23.0, 1.23.1, 1.23.2, 1.23.3, 1.23.4, 1.23.5)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.21.2
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I don't know what should i do. It keep gives same answer.
Also, when i tried to download mediapipe,
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
this always comes up. what can i do?

```
pip install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.6.0.66.tar.gz (90.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_machine == "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools==59.2.0
        Using cached setuptools-59.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
      Collecting wheel==0.37.0
        Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
      Collecting cmake>=3.1
        Using cached cmake-3.25.0-py2.py3-none-macosx_10_10_universal2.macosx_10_10_x86_64.macosx_11_0_arm64.macosx_11_0_universal2.whl (45.1 MB)
      Collecting pip
        Using cached pip-22.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
      Collecting scikit-build>=0.13.2
        Using cached scikit_build-0.16.2-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
      ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.5 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.6 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.21.2 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0rc1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0rc1, 1.19.0rc2, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5, 1.20.0rc1, 1.20.0rc2, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.20.3, 1.21.0rc1, 1.21.0rc2, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.22.0rc1, 1.22.0rc2, 1.22.0rc3, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.22.2, 1.22.3, 1.22.4, 1.23.0rc1, 1.23.0rc2, 1.23.0rc3, 1.23.0, 1.23.1, 1.23.2, 1.23.3, 1.23.4, 1.23.5)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.21.2
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a python version problem that generally occurs on new installations. I def suggest you downgrade your python to 3.8 and try again be sure to comment more problems if they come along!

Comment: I downgraded py python to 3.8 with anaconda. But it still gives same respond. And I also tried using Anaconda Navigator, it stucks at Solving package speifications

Comment: It is interesting that you still get the error( with a new environment I assume) have you tried conda install opencv-python conda can solve these problems within itself

Comment: I also tried conda install, but it says: Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve. I tried conda update all and many things, but it didn't work